# Eclipse ClearCase plugin and CCRC

Tags: eclipse, clearcase-remote-client

I am new to ClearCase and CCRC in particular. Can someone help me, please? I have a CCRC installed and I have a view. How can convert this view to a eclipse project and use the ClearCase plugin functionality?
I have tried to associate a project, but always seems to get:

> An internal error occurred during: "Refreshing ClearCase Resource States".
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Environment details:

- Eclipse Platform Version: 4.3.2
- Eclipse ClearCase Integration Version: 2.2.35.201406121752
- Rational ClearCase Remote Client Version: 7.1.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two are not related:

- once you have added an [existing web view to your ClearCase navigator](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21384188), you have a web view copy area path which contains the files locally.
- in Eclipse, you can define a new project, adding that project in the same folder as the web view local path: the goal is to define the `.project` and `.classpath` where the web view and the sources are.

If the Eclipse project is where the ClearCase view is, then the ClearCase options (checkouts, version tree, merge, ...) will be available.

Make sure to not use the [ClearCase Eclipse plugin from sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-ccase/) though: it works for classic ClearCase, not for CCRC.

Comment: Thank you! So, I can not use CCRC with sourceforge eclipse plugin, which is what I was trying to do ...

Comment: @AbyAaaAsdda exactly.

Comment: But what are my options, when I have only this ClearCase RC installed?

Comment: @AbyAaaAsdda First, remove that extra plugin, then use the CCRC GUI separately from Eclipse. Once you have a CCRC view, you can import its content as an Eclipse project (but the fact that this content comes from a CCRC view doesn't concern Eclipse)

Comment: OK, I got it, I guess - the CCRC can be used as stand alone RCP and as eclipse plugin. I have the RCP, but I find it more useful to have eclipse plugin rather than RCP. The problem is that I can not find a appropriate plugin version for me.

Comment: @AbyAaaAsdda maybe the official CCRC Eclipse plugin would work? http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_install_ccrc_eclipse.htm